# how to fix up code with java display

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
  class Enrolment{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.println("/*-------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("My name: XIANGYU QIAO");
  System.out.println("My student number: 5089864");
  System.out.println("My email address: xq907@uowmail.edu.au");
  System.out.println("Assignment number: 2");
  System.out.println("-------------------------------------*/");
  System.out.print("\nStudent " + Fullname + Email + Course+ Studentnumber);
  System.out.print("\nEnrolment " + Subjectcode + session + Year); 
}
}
     class Student{
      private static Formatter outStream;
     private static Scanner inStream;

    public Student() throws IOException  
  {
  outStream = new Formatter(new File("student1.txt")); 
  String fullName = "David Black";
  String email = "davblk@ipw.edu.au";
  String course = "1853E";
  sNumber = 375428;
    outStream.format("%s %s %s %i", fullName, email, course, sNumber);
 outStream.close();
  inStream = new Scanner( new File("student1.txt"));
  String Fullname = inStream.next();
  String Email = inStream.next();
 String Course = inStream.next();
 int Studentnumber = inStream.nextInt();
 inStream.close();

}
  public void displayStudInfo()
{
 System.out.print("\nStudent " + Fullname + Email + Course+ Studentnumber);
 }
}
class Subject{
 private static Formatter outStream;
    private static Scanner inStream;

    public Subject() throws IOException  
  {
  outStream = new Formatter(new File("subject1.txt")); 
  String sCode = "CSIT455";
  String session = "Autmn";
  int year = 2017;
    outStream.format("%s %s %i", sCode, session, year);
   outStream.close();
  inStream = new Scanner( new File("subject1.txt"));
  String Subjectcode = inStream.next();
  String Session = inStream.next();
 int Year = inStream.nextInt();
 inStream.close();
  System.out.print("\nEnrolment " + Subjectcode + session + Year);
 }
}
```

i am trying to create a file of student information and display it but i could not find a way to do that. could anyone help me to fix the code?
i am asked to display the student information in class Enrolment(main method here)and subject information that is given in class Student and Subject.i have no idea how to link these three things though it requires to use displayStudInfo method in class Student and displaySubjectInfo in class Subject.

Comment: What is the output of that code? and what you expected?

Comment: Hi, could you give a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish. What's exactly wrong with your code? If it's are review you are seeking maybe you should seek help at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: what are the other classes you have in the project? suppose we can help with you using OOP concepts.

Comment: There are many thing wrong with your code. The `Student` method declaration seem invalid and from my point of view I would say that you are trying to access variables local to the method `Student` within the method `displayStudInfo`. Does your code compile correctly?

Comment: Remy it compile correctly but it does not show anything except my personal details

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you cannot access properties from constructor in `displayStudInfo` method. So assigning those properties to class properties will resolve the issue.

```
class Student {

private final String fullname;
private final String email;
private final String course;
private final int studentNumber;

public Student() throws IOException {
    writeStudent();

    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(new File("student1.txt"));
    fullname = inStream.next();
    email = inStream.next();
    course = inStream.next();
    studentNumber = inStream.nextInt();
    inStream.close();
}

private void writeStudent() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Formatter outStream = new Formatter(new File("student1.txt"));

    outStream.format("%s %s %s %i", "David Black", "davblk@ipw.edu.au", "1853E", 375428);
    outStream.close();
}

public void displayStudInfo() {
    System.out.print("\nStudent " + fullname + email + course + studentNumber);
}
```

}

If you do not want to add any more class prop, you will need to ad arguments to your method:

```
public void displayStudInfo( String fullname,String email,String course, int studentNumber) {
    System.out.print("\nStudent " + fullname + email + course + studentNumber);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Beri. that perfectly resolved my problem~